# Android, How to customise look and feel of progressbar?

Tags: android, slider, progress-bar, customization, slideshow

I need to create a component such as progressbar (as you can see in image) to act as slider. I searched Internet and find somethings like:
[Custom Drawable for ProgressBar/ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819778/custom-drawable-for-progressbar-progressdialog)
but it was not useful for me. Please tell me how can i create this component?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own drawable, for example `progressbar.xml` and set `android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar` attrubute on your progress bar

write in `progressbar.xml` drawable this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
            <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/progressbar_bg" android:dither="true" />
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/progressbar_body" android:dither="true" />
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

and replace `@drawable/progressbar_bg` and `@drawable/progressbar_body` with you own 9 patch png images

Comment: I tried this and the progress value seems to be ignored in that case. So it always appears at 100%. Any suggestions?

Comment: ups, googling helps
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141469/android-seekbar-set-custom-style-using-nine-patch-images