# Android Seekbar with only Nine-Patch images

Tags: android, xml, seekbar, nine-patch

I am trying to make a seekbar with only nine-patch images. One nine patch is the background. I want to remove the thumb and want the other nine-patch to expand when I slide towards the right. Presently the thumb always appears.

I have tried the method given in this answer:
[Android seekbar set custom style using nine-patch images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141469/android-seekbar-set-custom-style-using-nine-patch-images)

But this also gives an extra thumb. And on sliding right the nine patch appears complete only when I am done sliding till the extreme right. [Here is my nine patch image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgyVE.png) and I want the arm to increase as I go towards the right on the seekbar.

Any help?

P.S. by thumb I mean the seekbar thumb and not the thumb in the image.

[Need to make an image like this](http://postimg.org/image/p6wjoti21/)

Comment: tried `setThumb(null)`?

Comment: Yes it did work. But two issues still remain. 1) My 9-patch is coming below my seekbar for some reason. 2) The thumb part of my 9-patch appears when i reach the extreme right. Whereas I want it to be there since beginning and just the arm to increase. Any help?

Comment: so it seems you have to draw your "thumb from your image" by hand, see how to extend `Drawable` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30873744/2252830)

Comment: Drawing the thumb. Doesn't seem like a solution. I am looking for something like this. I feel it has to be done using 9-patch only. http://postimg.org/image/p6wjoti21/

Comment: in theory you can do it by: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/thumb" android:scaleWidth="100%"/>` but the results are, hmm, not so good

Comment: I basically need to replace the thumb with a 9-patch. If you can suggest some way for that, then that'd be great. Thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: i already did it: have you tried my previous comment?

Comment: Didn't understand where to place it. Here is my seekbar xml, `<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="40dp"
        android:minHeight="9dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/search_progress_clip" />`

Comment: read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: And here is my search_progress_clip. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/rsz_thumbsup1" android:dither="true"/>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="left"><nine-patch android:src="@drawable/rsz_thumbsup1" android:dither="true"/></clip> </item>
</layer-list>`

Comment: i sent you a progress drawable, just use it

Comment: That worked sir, Brilliant. But just one last problem. This is my seekbar `<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar_bar"  style="android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"android:maxHeight="100dp" android:minHeight="9dp" android:progressDrawable="@drawable/search_progress_clip" />` and the progress Drawable is what you sent. The background line disappears now. How do I get a background line or image?

Comment: use a `<layer-list>` then

Comment: I did this. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/image" android:dither="true"/>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:drawable="@drawable/rsz_thumbsup1"
            android:scaleWidth="100%"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>`. But my background also fills the whole height while I want it to be in the middle of my progress.

Comment: so your background needs to be "scaled" by a `<scale>` drawable, so place it inside `<scale>`

Comment: Did this. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:drawable="@drawable/image"
            android:scaleWidth="150%"/>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rsz_thumbsup1" android:scaleWidth="100%"/> </item> </layer-list>`. Any % shows no background. What to do?

Comment: use one <scale> and inside place background and thumb

Comment: But a scale can't have two drawables?

Comment: sure `<scale>` cannot have two `Drawable`s, that's why i suggested to read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: so it seems you have to draw your "thumb from your image" by hand. This is what you said. So the arm can still be a nine-patch? And I use the custom drawable as the seekbar thumb. Is that what you're suggesting?